# Replace checkbox with image asp.net

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

This is what I have tried, I think the question is self-explainatory.

**Using CSS:** (This did not work I did a jsfiddle)

```
.star + label{
    background:url('image1.png') no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

.star:checked + label{
    background:url('image2.png') no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

**Using jQuery** (This worked partially)

```
$('.star').replaceWith("<img src='image1.png' />");

$('.star').click(function () {
var $checkbox = $(this).prev(".star");
$checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

    if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
        $image.attr("src", "image2.png");
    } else {
        $image.attr("src", "image1.png");
    }
})
```

JSFIDDLE: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jdq9u8hh/3/)

And this is my code on the aspx page:

```
    <span>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="star1" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="star2" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="star3" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="star4" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="star5" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
    </span>
```

What could I be doing wrong? I have looked for multiple solutions (there are a lot of questions here about it) but they don't handle the case in which it is asp.NET.

Comment: Hello Joze, why the jQuery method worked partially? Whats is missing?

Comment: @KauêGimenes The uncheked image shows but on click nothing happens. The jQuery does *not* work on the .net project though. In the fiddle I tested making inputs, not exactly the same as the asp:checkboxes....

Comment: Total guess (as I'm a newbie in jQuery), but if you're replacing the HTML element that has the `class="star"` with the image... then the next piece of code is not going to find any elements with `class="star"` to bind to?  Try putting the `class="star"` as part of the `<img>` code you're using to replace

Comment: @freefaller no that's not it either. Though I will leave the class attribute on the img tag. I think that was still a mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: My next question was going to be what @Abdul has just answered... I thought the format was `$(".star").on("click", function() { ... });`

Comment: if you inspect element on jsfidde, you will see the console error: `can't find variable: $image`

Comment: see my updated answer, with the fiddle on top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Heres a working demo for you](https://jsfiddle.net/jdq9u8hh/5/)

for `jQuery`, binding a `.click` event handler on dynamically generated content (in your case, the image) will not work. You need to use the following syntax:

```
$('.star').on('click', function() { });
```

although, even this has not worked for me in the past, and I had to do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.star', function() { });
```

***update***

let's look at your code together real quick:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //write your code here
  $('.star').replaceWith("<img src='https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav_bleu.png' class='star'/>");

  $('.star').click(function () {
    var $image = '';
    var $checkbox = $(this).prev(".star");
    $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

    if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
        $image.attr("src", "https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav.png");
    } else {
        $image.attr("src", "https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav_bleu.png");
    }
  })
});
```

the first thing you need to know is that you haven't declared an `$image` variable, which I did for you. The second thing is, the `$image` variable must be a jQuery object before you can call `.attr` on it. So you need to declare this `$image` object something like this:

```
var $image = $(this);
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. check the fiddle I put on the question

Comment: @Joze, your fiddle does not use the format that Abdul has given you.  Also, the fiddle is not even showing the initial image, so it's pretty difficult to tell what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Leading on from the answer from @Abdul, and his comment about the missing `$image`, your jsfiddle has a couple of errors.

Here is a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/jdq9u8hh/4/) (although as I say, the images aren't appearing - but viewing the src through development tools shows it is changing).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     //write your code here
    $('.star').replaceWith("<img src='https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav_bleu.png' class='star'/>");

    $('.star').on("click", function () {
        var $checkbox = $(this);
        $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));

        if ($checkbox.prop("checked")) {
            $checkbox.prop("src", "https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav.png");
        } else {
            $checkbox.prop("src", "https://cm.eid-bad.e-i.com/cmcee/fr/images/std/icofav_bleu.png");
        }
    })
});
```

The first mistake was that you were taking all the elements with `class='star'` and replacing them with an image.  But the image did not have the `class='star'` attribute... therefore when it tried to bind on the next statement, there were no elements to bind to (because you'd just replaced them all.

The binding itself was incorrectly formatted (I believe that might be an old style of binding) and should have been using the `.on("click", function() { ... });` style.

Then you were using `$(this).prev('.star');` when what you actually wanted was just `$(this)`.

Finally you were then trying to use `$image` which didn't exist - but in fact it was the object itself that you were trying to change... so once again what you actually wanted was `$(this)` (which you'd set to `$checkbox`)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that ASP.NET framework do not render

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="star1" CssClass="star" runat="server" />
```

like this.

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="star1" class="star" value="1" />
```

Instead, it gets rendered as ( yet another ASP.NET discrepancy )

```
<span class="star">
    <input id="star1" type="checkbox" name="star1" />
</span>
```

Change your click function keeping this DOM structure in mind to make the code work.